# URL-decode function : what is it doing exactly ? explanation needed

Tags: c

This is a function that URL-**decodes** a string.

It works ok. I would like some info on what exactly it is doing.

- which characters is it replacing with what.
- why must **isxdigit** function be used ?

perhaps one day i will re-code it in a manner so that it visually
does not look as confusing as it does right now.

```
void url_decode(char *dst, const char *src){
        char a, b;
        while (*src) {
                if ((*src == '%') &&
                    ((a = src[1]) && (b = src[2])) &&
                    (isxdigit(a) && isxdigit(b))) {
                        if (a >= 'a')
                                a -= 'a'-'A';
                        if (a >= 'A')
                                a -= ('A' - 10);
                        else
                                a -= '0';
                        if (b >= 'a')
                                b -= 'a'-'A';
                        if (b >= 'A')
                                b -= ('A' - 10);
                        else
                                b -= '0';
                        *dst++ = 16*a+b;
                        src+=3;
                } else if (*src == '+') {
                        *dst++ = ' ';
                        src++;
                } else {
                        *dst++ = *src++;
                }
        }
        *dst++ = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `isxdigit` doesn't have to be used...but it's a lot more simple and readable  than alternatives for deciding if a character is a hex digit.

Comment: The function seems to replace a `%2D` string (for example) with the hex value.

Comment: @MatteoItalia that shouldn't be the case - `(a = src[1])` will fail if it's a NUL for example - same for the assignment to `b`

Comment: Try it with a debugger.

Comment: @ChrisTurner: uh right, I got a bit mixed up with the assignments in the conditionals, which is a shame since I wrote code like that myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function copies a URL from the string pointed to by `src` to an array pointed to by `dst`, converting sequences of `%xx` with 2 hexadecimal digits to the single character they represent.

The 2 characters following the `%` are stored into `a` and `b`, testing that they are not `'\0'` bytes and verifying that they are hexadecimal digits with `isxdigit()`.

Note however that the `char` values should be converted to `unsigned char` before calling `isxdigit` to avoid undefined behavior for negative values.

Also note that the tests are redundant since `isxdigit()` returns false for null bytes.

The characters are then converted to lower-case and then to the numeric value they represent.

The resulting character is computed `16 * a + b` and stored into `dst`.

`+` signs are converted to spaces, other characters are left unchanged.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void url_decode(char *dst, const char *src) {
    unsigned char a, b;
    while (*src) {
        if (*src == '%'
        &&  isxdigit(a = tolower((unsigned char)src[1]))
        &&  isxdigit(b = tolower((unsigned char)src[2]))) {
            a -= isdigit(a) ? '0' : 'a';
            b -= isdigit(b) ? '0' : 'a';
            *dst++ = 16 * a + b;
            src += 3;
        } else
        if (*src == '+') {
            *dst++ = ' ';
            src++;
        } else {
            *dst++ = *src++;
        }
    }
    *dst = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Would it be clearer to use a `switch(*src)` rather than the chained `if` `else if` `else` statements?

Comment: @Baldrickk: actually it would not because if the extra test for 2 hexdecimal characters. The `switch` case for `'%'` would either have duplicate code or branch to the default code wich the case `'+'` would not. For just 3 branches, the `if / else` sequence is clear enough.